# MySQLi get_result alternative for PHP < 5.3?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a big problem

```
public function get_setting($setting) {
    // Prepate statement
    $prepared = $this->prepare("SELECT `val` FROM `filex_settings` WHERE `setting`=?", 'get_setting');
    $this->bind_param($prepared->bind_param('s', $setting), 'get_setting()');
    $this->execute($prepared, 'get_setting()');
    $result = $prepared->get_result();// < 5.3 PHP
    $row = $result->fetch_object();
    return $row->val;
}
```

Alternative please ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: If it is at all possible, you are highly advised to move off of PHP 5.2. It has been unsupported for several years and has quite a few known vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `fetch()` with `bind_result()` instead.

```
public function get_setting($setting) {
    // Prepate statement
    $prepared = $this->prepare("SELECT `val` FROM `filex_settings` WHERE `setting`=?", 'get_setting');
    $this->bind_param($prepared->bind_param('s', $setting), 'get_setting()');
    $this->execute($prepared, 'get_setting()');
    $this->bind_result($col_1,$col_2,..)
    while($this->fetch())
    {
        return $col_n // the value which you want
    }  
}
```

Comment: `bind_result()` won't place an object in `$row` as `$row->val`.  It takes variable references, so an output variable `$val` should be bound in and used directly in the `fetch()` loop http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php  Each column in the `SELECT` requires a separate variable bound in `bind_result()`.